# What generates the torque to rotate this micromirror around the _vertical_ axis?

Tags: electromagnetism, mems

[image]

I can see current in the coil could interact with a magnetic field could cause the coil to rotate around the horizontal axis (flexures 310 and 312), but what forces are making the inner micromirror rotate around the vertical axis (flexures 320 and 322)?

Or am I missing something in the mechanics and 310 and 312 somehow *stretch* and 320 and 322 do not twist?

From the patent:

> In operation, an external magnetic field source (not shown) imposes a magnetic field on the drive coil. The magnetic field imposed on the drive coil by the external magnetic field source has a component in the plane of the coil, and is oriented at roughly 45° with respect to the two drive axes. The in-plane current in the coil windings interacts with the in-plane magnetic field to produce out-of-plane Lorentz forces on the conductors. Since the drive current forms a loop on gimbal 340, the current reverses sign across the scan axes. This means the Lorentz forces also reverse sign across the scan axes, resulting in a torque in the plane of and normal to the magnetic field. This combined torque produces responses in the two scan directions depending on the frequency content of the torque.

From this great write up...
https://www.techinsights.com/blog/look-inside-microvisions-picop-projector-technology

Comment: The external orthogonal vertical axis magnetic field is hidden from this view but a raster scan must have a fast retrace < 10% with a linear sawtooth controlled ramp with the onboard coil at 16 kHz ?? while the external sawtooth operates at 30 Hz for interlace or 59 Hz for non-interlace.  But this backdoor firmware makes me go hmmm https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/second-chinese-firm-in-a-week-found-hiding-backdoor-in-firmware-of-android-devices/

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Sorry, but huh? Either I am even dumber than I thought (very possible) or you turned into a GPT3?